# Writing \x00 into a file

Tags: c++, hex

I have to send a hex command to a USB device.

The command is:

```
echo -en "\x1b\x70\x00\x19\xfa" > /dev/usb/lp0
```

If I write it on the terminal, it works. However, in C++ there is a problem with the hex command. `\x00` is detected as a null-terminated string.

I have tried two methods:

```
std::string cmd = "echo '\\x1b\\x70\\x00\\x19\\xfa' > /dev/usb/lp0";
std::system(cmd.c_str());
```

Nothing happens.

And:

```
std::ofstream device;
device.open("/dev/usb/lp0");
device << "\x1b\x70\x00\x19\xfa";
device.close();
```

The device doesn't do anything.

How can I get around this problem and use the `\x00` string?

Comment: Don't forget you need to escape back slashes in string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using an array of `unsigned char`, rather than a C-string or std::string, to store the command:

```
const unsigned char usb_cmd[] = { 0x1b, 0x70, 0x00, 0x19, 0xfa };
```

This way it is obvious to readers that this is a message in a binary protocol, not text and not a nul-terminated string.  Also, declared this way, `sizeof(usb_cmd)` will be the correct number of bytes to write, not one more, and not `sizeof(char*)` either.  If you need to vary the contents of the command at runtime, use a `vector<unsigned char>` instead.

I would also do the actual write to the device with operating system primitives:

```
int fd = open("/dev/usb/lp0", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("/dev/usb/lp0");
    return -1;
}
ssize_t nwritten = write(fd, usb_cmd, sizeof usb_cmd);
if ((size_t)nwritten != sizeof usb_cmd) {
    if (nwritten < 0) {
        perror("/dev/usb/lp0: write error");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "/dev/usb/lp0: short write (%zu of %zu bytes)\n",
                (size_t)nwritten, sizeof usb_cmd);
    }
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}
close(fd);
return 0;
```

This way, you can be sure that exactly the correct number of bytes are written, all at once; there are no encoding or buffering layers to interfere.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function to write a fixed length of bytes.

And since you're writing binary data I suggest you open the file in binary mode as well, and write actual integer values instead of a string.

---

Example code

```
std::ofstream device ("/dev/usb/lp0",std::ofstream::binary);
std::uint8_t const message[] = { 0x1b, 0x70, 0x00, 0x19, 0xfa };
if (device)
    device.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(message), sizeof message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide an example? So std::ofstream device ("/dev/usb/lp0",std::ofstream::binary) to write in binary. How would the write function be?

Comment: @grouser Added example.

Comment: It gives the error invalid conversion from ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘const char*

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, I recommend adding `device.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);` right after `device` is instantiated, so you don't have stream buffers interfering.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much both, @Someprogrammerdude and zwol